# How to display child routes in Angular on their own page for correct breadcrumb nesting

Tags: angular

I’m trying to get xng-breadcrumb to work which is based on routes, and it's working fine except I can’t figure out how to define a route for a component that is a child of another page, and not have it display within the same page using routeroutlet.

For example, I have a parent page with a button to view a page which is a conceptual child of that page as far as breadcrumbs would be concerned.  So my path is something like home/entity/123/info.

So in this example 'entity' would go to an entity search page, '123' is an entity id, and 'info' would be a page showing some additional info for that entity on a new page.

In my main app module I have the 'home/entity' defined and pointing to a child module.  And in that child module I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SearchComponent
  },
  {
    path: ":entityId",
    component: EntityProfileComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "info",
        component: AdditionalInfoComponent
      },
      {
        path: "",
        component: EntityProfileComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Where I have a child ngmodule (ex. home/entity/123), it works as expected.  But if I have a child defined within a module like shown above, Angular seems to insist that the child component must be displayed within the same page of the parent via `<routeroutlet></routeroutlet>`.  If I leave off `<routeroutlet></routeroutlet>` it just displays the parent page for the child page's route.

So I don't understand how I'm supposed to define the nesting relationship for the breadcrumbs to work correctly without having child components somehow display within the same page as their parent components, or without having to define a new Angular module file for every level of nesting that I want for the breadcrumbs.

Why doesn't Angular simply display a child component on a new page if there's no `<routeroutlet></routeroutlet>` defined in the parent page, instead of quietly failing and contradicting what has been configured in the module route definition?

Answer (score 1):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SearchComponent
  },
{
    path: ":entityId",
    component: EntityProfileComponent},
  {
    path: ":entityId",
    children: [
      {
        path: "info",
        component: AdditionalInfoComponent
      },
      {
        path: "",
        component: EntityProfileComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

it will display in its child component instead of the parent component. It working for me.